# Issues with sqlSave in R?

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, sql-server-2012, rodbc

I've read through previous questions/answers concerning this issue but none seemed to answer my problem. My end goal is to get data from R into a SQL table.

In trying to do so, I first created the table `[PL_DEV].[PL_A].[X]` in Microsoft SQL Server 2012 with the following columns: `ST VARCHAR(10)`, `YEAR VARCHAR(10)`, `Intercept FLOAT`, `Y FLOAT`, `Z FLOAT`, `U FLOAT`. A primary key was added to the `ST`, `YEAR` columns.

From there, I established an RODBC connection which I am calling `conn`.

After setting that up, I created a data-frame called `df` that looks like this for the first row of data:

```
 ST    YEAR      INTERCEPT   Y           Z          U
"01"   "2009"   -50012.37    0.6341358   16569.52   61.42544
```

Once this was set, I attempted to insert data from this data-frame (`df`) into the SQL table I had created (`[PL_DEV].[PL_A].[X]`). I attempted to do that with the following statement:

```
sqlSave(conn, dat = df, tablename = "[PL_DEV].[PL_A].[X]", append = TRUE, rownames = FALSE)
```

I set `append = TRUE` so that it wouldn't create the table but rather insert data and also set `rownames = FALSE` so it wouldn't add an extra/unnecessary column.

However, when I execute the statement above, I get the following error:

> Error in sqlSave(conn, df, tablename = "[PL_DEV].[PL_A].[X]", :
>   42S01 2714 [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]
>   There is already an object named 'X' in the database.
>   [RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'CREATE TABLE [PL_DEV].[PL_A].[X]
>   ("ST" varchar(255), "YEAR" varchar(255), "INTERCEPT" float, "Y" float, 
>   "Z" float, "U" float)'

I can get data to insert into a SQL table (`[master].[dbo].[df]` to be more specific) if I execute the following:

```
sqlSave(conn, dat = df)
```

However, once data is in this table, the same issue arises and I cannot insert more data into the table.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or another function that will do the same thing for me? I just started programming in R this past week. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a work around.

For the first iteration of my loop, I used the following command:

```
sqlSave(conn, dat = df, rownames = FALSE)
```

For iterations 2 through n of my loop, I used the following command:

```
sqlSave(conn, dat = df, append = TRUE, rownames = FALSE)
```

This created a table [dbo].[df] in the database [PL_DEV] for me (since I set up my RODBC directly to that database).